# How do I Loop through a schedule in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, logic, reporting

I'm building a report in Crystal Reports 2008. The report is dealing with employee's schedules. There are time slots where the schedule is open, and time slots where the schedule is unavailable.

Currently, I've built my logic so that it finds the start and end of an unavailable time. The report them tells me how many hours that particular staff person was unavailable.

My issue is that sometimes, staff people have a block at the beginning of their schedule marked as 'unavailable', and a block at the end of the day as 'unavailable', but between the two they are 'open'. Thus, the report says that particular staff person was out the whole day, but they actually worked. It isn't an option to tell these particular staff people how to schedule their day - they decide their own schedule, and I write the report to accomodate their needs.

```
SCHEDULE_TIME   EMP_ID  UNAVAILABLE_CODE    WORK_LENGTH
7/5/2011 11:00  100     NULL                    15
7/5/2011 11:15  100     NULL                    15
7/5/2011 11:30  100     NULL                    15
7/5/2011 11:45  100     NULL                    15
7/5/2011 12:00  100     15                      5
7/5/2011 17:00  100     15                      5
```

This example shows how somebody would have a 5 hour block calculated for unavailable time, but it's only 2 appointments. For the code, I'm using DATEDIFF between appointment times.

(Essentially, they have built in more than one 'unavailable' block, and my logic will only accomodate one 'unavailable' block per day).

I'm pretty sure that I need to run a type of DO...WHILE loop within the report in order to calculate the total hours unavailable. I'm just not sure how to structure the loop in Crystal Reports.

Comment: Could you include more technical details about your report? What does the data model look like? How are you calculating these blocks, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe i'm missing something but what you want to do looks straight forward. Two obvious options:

1. Running total: 
   Set the field to {TABLE.WORK_LENGTH}
   Set the type to sum
   Set the evaluation formula to not(isnull({TABLE.UNAVAILABLE_CODE}))
   Set the reset on change of group/field {TABLE.EMP_ID} (assuming you're looking for totals per employee)
2. Formula/sum:
   Create a formula field unavailable_time with `if not(isnull({TABLE.UNAVAILABLE_CODE})) then {TABLE.WORK_LENGTH} else 0`
   Create a group on {TABLE.EMP_ID}
   Create a sum on your formula field in the group footer

Comment: You may have hit it on the head - the only issue is that it is a command object, and hence I need to program the unavailable_time formulae into SQL, then perhaps use the running total or just a sum. I'll give it a shot, and thanks!